# How to open a new popup or window using tr tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

this is my script

```
tr style='cursor:hand' onclick="javascript:location.href='list.php?no=$row[no]'"
```

it pops up in same window :

I think I have to use someting like

```
onclick="javascript:[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;]='list.php?no=$row[no]'"
```

How can I have new popup or window?

I used a `href=` but it didn't work in chrome so I don't want to use a `href` tag.

Comment: I did a google and within seconds found this tool http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php while you took minutes to write up this question, how about that?

Answer (score 1):

try with this `window.open`

`tr style='cursor:hand' onclick="javascript:window.open('list.php?no=$row[no]');"`

see [window.open](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html)

**update 2**

`tr style='cursor:hand' onclick="javascript:window.open('list.php?no=$row[no]', 'my_window');"`

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a function like this

```
function openPopUp(url)
{
    var newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

and than you should have a code like this

```
tr style='cursor:hand' onclick="openPopUp('list.php?no=$row[no]')"
```

it will open new popup with height 200 and width 150